# how to iterate overobject in a class

Tags: python

i want to be able to iterate over my class but the interpretter keep saying that object are not iterable there for sure a ways to get a around that

```
class bloc():
    


    def __init__(self,vitesse=0,position=(0,0),masse=0):
        self.vitesse=vitesse
        self.position=position
        self.masse=masse


        
bloc1=bloc(10,(0,0),15)
bloc2=bloc(15,(1,4),13)


for obj in bloc :
   print(obj.position)
```

the out put that i want is

```
(0,0)
(1,4)
```

Comment: Okay, third try at this comment, because I misunderstood you twice :) I thought you want to iterate over the *attributes* of an *instance* of the class, but in fact you want to iterate *over the instances*. You cannot "iterate over the objects in the class" like that because the instances (objects created from the class) aren't "in" the class. You need to keep track of them yourself, for example in a list.

Comment: Classes are not containers for their instances; just use a regular list: `blocs = [bloc(10, (0,0), 15), bloc(15, (1,4), 13)]`.

Comment: You could have your class keep track of all the instances it creates in a list, probably using weak references, and then you could use a metaclass that implements the iterator protocol, iterating over that list. **But why?** Just keep the list yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list add each instance and then iterate through the desired attributes.

```
instances = []
class bloc():

    def __init__(self, vitesse=0, position=(0, 0), masse=0):
        instances.append(self)
        self.vitesse = vitesse
        self.position = position
        self.masse = masse


bloc1 = bloc(10, (0, 0), 15)
bloc2 = bloc(15, (1, 4), 13)

for obj in instances:
    print(obj.position)

>>> (0, 0)
    (1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bloc_list = []

class Bloc():

    def __init__(self,vitesse=0,position=(0,0),masse=0):
        self.vitesse=vitesse
        self.position=position
        self.masse=masse
        bloc_list.append(self)



bloc1=Bloc(10,(0,0),15)
bloc2=Bloc(15,(1,4),13)


for obj in bloc_list:
    print(obj.position)

print(bloc_list)
```

Create a list and append the new object every time the `__init__` method is called.